# Using Include, require, file_get_contents, readfile for getting $_SERVER

Tags: php

Why whenever I use include, require, file_get_contents or readfile for getting $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] it gives me a different result?

**file1.php**
website: example1.com

```
<?php
  //sample code inside this file

  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

**file2.php**
website: example2.com

```
<?php
  require("example1.com/file1.php"); //result: example1.com

  //my expected result is example2.com
?>
```

my expected result inside file2.php is **example2.com** but it only displays example1.com instead of example2.com. why $_SERVER only works on the other side and not working as expected when it suppose to just get the code?



Just to make everything clear:

here's an example:
example1.com
file1.php
inside file1.php is $_SERVER['server_name'];



example2.com
include example1.com/file1.php


example3.com
include example1.com/file1.php


what I want to happen is to display each websites url in their own website using the centralized file(file1.php from example.com)


but the problem is each website is display **example1.com** instead of their own website url.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what exactly the situation is. The `$_SERVER` variable is initialised from the HTTP request. Any subsequent files you include are all in the same HTTP request context and share the same `$_SERVER` variable. The variable won't change from one file to another within the same request.

Comment: so that means there's no other way to include a $_SERVER to another file but to put it directly in the file2.php?

Comment: I'm still really not clear on what you're asking. What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: @deceze

what I really want to happen is to get the url of example2.com.

I'm using this kind of scenario because I'm doing a centralized file where I will only include file1.php inside file2.php, file3.php, file4.php. and each file will display it's current server url not the file1.php server url

Comment: A *file* doesn't have a URL. Or it could have a bazillion different URLs which all lead to the same file. What you want doesn't make sense.

Comment: here's an example:<br/>
example.com<br/>
file1.php<br/>
inside file is $_SERVER['server_name'];
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
example2.com<br/>
include example.com/file1.php<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
example3.com<br/>
include example.com/file1.php<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
what I want to happen is to display each websites url in their own website using the centralized file(file1.php from example.com)<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
but the problem is each website is display **example1.com** instead of their own website url.

Comment: Is your code `include 'http://example.com/file1.php';`? The important part being `http://`!

Comment: Then of course, you're making a separate HTTP request to another server. It's the same as entering that address in your browser.

Comment: I'm making it dynamically using a centralized file without coding the "$_SERVER['server_name']" to each website's file but by only including the file1.php with a $_SERVER['server_name'] inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

*website*:**www.example-one.com**
*file*:**linkone.php**

```
<?php 
$addrone = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

*website*:**www.example-two.com**
*file*:**linktwo.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'www.example-one.com'; // Adds $addrone;
    $addrtwo = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    document.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(document.readyState == "complete")
        {
            var onex = document.getElementById("one");
            var twox = document.getElementById("two");
            onex.onclick = function()
            {
                alert("<?php echo $addrone; ?>");
            }
            twox.onclick = function()
            {
                alert("<?php echo $addrtwo; ?>");
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="one">one</button>
    <button id="two">two</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `require("example1.com/file1.php"); //result: example1.com` you are not requiring the code. You are requiring result of execution of code. If you what include code itself just rename your `file1.php` to, for example, `file1.txt`.

Comment: In my situation I cannot use this. sorry.

Comment: @GlenDraco, you cannot affect on the other server behaviour.